# problem in plotting phase portrait t for nonlinear system of difference equation

Tags: plotting, manipulate, difference-equations

I have tried to do a code about phase portrait plot for this system of difference equation:

\begin{align}
x_{t+1} &= ax_{t}^2+y_t+1  \\
y_{t+1} &= bx_t^2-1
\end{align}
I took 'a=0.5','b=2'

but it doesnt work ,may i have a problem in command iteration of that dynamics

**Code**:

```
t:=i+1;
splot = LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{0.5 x^2 + y + 1, 
            2 x^2 - 1}, {"noise", 1000, 1000}}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 
           3}, {i, 0, 50}, ColorFunction -> "BeachColors", 
          LightingAngle -> 0, LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 3, 
          Frame -> False];
       Manipulate[
        Show[splot, 
         ParametricPlot[
          Evaluate[
           First[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
             NDSolve[{x[t] == 2 x[t - 1]^2 + y[t - 1] + 1, 
               y[t] == 2 x[t - 1]^2 - 1, 
               Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}, i, 
              0, 50}]]], {t, 0, T}, PlotStyle -> White]], {{T, 20}, 1,
   100}, {{point, {3, 0}}, Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

then where is the probelm in my above code ?

Comment: Even `splot` doesn't evaluate, returning a basic syntax error. You need to start from there and fix that first, before you worry about the `Manipulate` code.

Comment: Your system is discrete-time (difference equations), but `NDSolve` is for continuous-time differential equations.  You should look into `RecurrenceTable` or `NestList` instead.

Comment: Also, not sure if the phase plot tells you what you want, because $x_{t+1}$ differs from $dx/dt$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a modification of your code that runs on my machine, I hope this is what you wanted to do. Please `Quit[]` before you use this to avoid problems with previous definitions.

```
(* background plot *)
xmax=4; ymax=3;
splot=LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{0.5 x^2+y+1,2 x^2-1},{"noise",1000,1000}},{x,-xmax,xmax},{y,-ymax,ymax},ColorFunction->"BeachColors",LightingAngle->0,LineIntegralConvolutionScale->3,Frame->False];

(* code to solve recurrence *)
sol[point_,T_]:=Module[{t,x,y},Select[RecurrenceTable[{x[t]==2 x[t-1]^2+y[t-1]+1,y[t]==2 x[t-1]^2-1,Thread[{x[0],y[0]}==N[point]]},{x,y},{t,0,Round[T]}],And[-xmax<=#[[1]]<=xmax,-ymax<=#[[2]]<=ymax]&]];

(* Manipulate *)
Manipulate[Show[splot,ListPlot[sol[point,T],PlotStyle->White]],{{T,20},1,100},{{point,{3,0}},Locator},SaveDefinitions->True]
```

[image]

**Here is what I modified.** Removed `t:=i+1` which caused problem. Removed `{i,0,50}`. Used `RecurrenceTable` instead of `NDSolve`. Used `ListPlot` instead of `ParametricPlot`. Used `Select` to drop points outside the field of view, to avoid `PlotRange` errors.